# Indirekte Rede nutzen oder nicht?

Tags: style, indirect-speech, quotes

In einem Aufsatz zitiere ich eine Umfrage:

> **Was ist für die Jugendlichen wichtig**:
>
> > 91% – toll aussehen
> >           83% – Karriere machen
> >           usw.

Ich habe geschrieben:

> „Toll aussehen“ sei heutzutage der größte Wunsch der Jugend (…) Danach folge das Bedürfnis, eine Karriere zu machen.

Habe ich hier die indirekte Rede falsch gebraucht? Vielleicht sollte man einfach im Indikativ schreiben?

Der ganze Aufsatz als Kontext: https://spideroak.com/share/NVQXE3LJON2HE6TNMFZA/public/home/marcin/SpiderOak%20Hive/public/indirekte.odt

Comment: Das kommt auf den weiteren Zusammenhang an und darauf, wie sehr du dir die Ergebnisse der Umfrage zu eigen machst. Es kann richtig sein oder auch nicht.

Comment: Aus den Antorten und deiner Erwähnung von "Konjunktiv" schließe ich, dass es dir vor allem um das "sei" geht. Ist das richtig? Denn der Beispielsatz an sich hat, wenn, dann direkte Rede ... du benutzt ja Anführungsstriche. Ich denke, man sollte den Titel ändern, aber ich will nix ändern, was deinem INteresse zuwiderläuft.

Comment: 2 Wörter sind kein Zitat. Toll aussehen braucht keine Anführungsstriche; sie sind da fehl am Platze.

Comment: Die Anführungsstriche habe ich deshalb hinzugefüht, weil ich die Antwort einer Umfrage zitiere.

Comment: Was hat das mit *zurückgreifen* zu tun (vom falsch platzierten *ü* abgesehen)?

Comment: @userunknown: Da würde ich widersprechen, die Anführungszeichen sollten da durchaus hin. Durch die Anführungszeichen wird nämlich ausgedrückt, dass es sich bei der Formulierung "toll aussehen" eben nicht um die Wortwahl des Autors handelt, sondern um die Wortwahl der befragten Jugendlichen. Ohne die Anführungszeichen wäre das nicht erkennbar.

Comment: @guidot: das sollte "referring (to something)" sein und das hat ein Wörterbuch vorgeschlagen

Comment: @marmistrz: "(auf etwas) zurückgreifen" bedeutet eher so etwas wie "to resort (to something)", "to make use (of some fallback plan or option)", daher ergibt hier "zurückgreifen" nicht viel Sinn. "referring (to something)" würde besser als "sich auf etwas beziehen" oder "auf etwas Bezug nehmen" ausgedrückt werden. Inhaltlich finde ich aber auch das eher unpassend.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Es ist aber wohl nicht de Wortwahl der Jugendlichen sondern eine Antwortoption eines Fragebogens, also kein Zitat.

Comment: @userunknown: Dann ist es ein Zitat aus dem Fragebogen, beziehungsweise eine wörtliche Wiedergabe dessen, was die Jugendlichen gesehen und angekreuzt haben. In jedem Fall sind die Anführungszeichen erforderlich, um klarzustellen, dass es nicht die eigene Wortwahl des Autors ist (der damit zumindest in einem wissenschaftlich neutral formulierten Text einen Stilbruch erzeugt hätte).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Im Gegenteil. Ein Zitat das aus 2 Wörtern besteht ist ein Witz. Die wörtliche Rede markiert hier nur einen Teil des Satzes "Toll aussehen ist der größte Wunsch der Jugend." Du selbst weißt auf Anhieb offenbar nicht, ob es ein Zitat der Befragten ist, des Fragebogenentwurfs oder des Fazit der Studie. Zitate aus dem Zusammenhang zu reißen ist schon eine Untugend, 2 Wörter als Zitat zu verkaufen ist Pseudopräzision.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich weiß auf Anhieb, dass es nicht die Wortwahl des Autors ist, und somit ist eine Kennzeichnung als Zitat notwendig. Das ist freilich unabhängig davon, ob es sich um zwei Wörter, um ein Wort, oder um fünfzig Wörter handelt. Falls nicht einleuchtet, wieso es sinnvoll ist, zumindest diesen Grad an Sorgfalt einzuhalten, wenn man einen Text schreibt, ist dies aber vermutlich eher ein Thema für eine separate Frage.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ich orientiere mich da lieber an [BelllesLettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/richtig-zitieren.php).

Comment: @userunknown Lässt man die Anführungszeichen weg, entsteht ein Satz, der grammatikalisch falsch ist - Da fehlt dann mindestens ein "zu".

Comment: @tof Dann ist er falsch, kann aber durch Anführungszeichen nicht geheilt werden. Anführungszeichen kennzeichnen die direkte Rede, das "sei" markiert aber unmissverständlich indirekte Rede.

Comment: @userunknown Der Rechtschreibrat (der muss es ja wissen) listet als Sinn und Zweck der Anführungszeichen außer der direkten Rede noch *Hervorhebungen, Sprichwörter, Wörter und Wortgruppen, auf die man Bezug nehmen will, zu Kommentierendes, Ironisches und Übertragenes...* Das Dritte dürfte hier zutreffen.

Comment: @tofro: Und wieso wird dann "eine Karriere zu machen" nicht ebenfalls eingetüttelt? Entweder beides oder keins von beiden - so ist es inkonsistent. Und besser ist natürlich keins von Beidem, denn den Bezug stellt das "sei" ausreichend und unzweideutig her.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Danke für den Kontext, leider hat der nicht so viel Aussagekraft, wie ich mir gewünscht hätte.

Es gibt zwei extreme Fälle, und irgendwo in der Mitte dazwischen bewegst du dich. Du solltest dir beide Extremfälle anschauen, und dann überlegen, welcher besser zutrifft.

### Fall 1: Die Umfrage ist von dir/direkten Kollegen von dir.

In diesem Fall solltest du selbstverfreilich den Indikativ verwenden. Schließlich hast du oder haben deine Kollegen die Umfrage durchgeführt, und du/ihr solltest/solltet keine Zweifel an ihrer Korrektheit haben. Beachte, dass die Umfrage in diesem Fall *trotzdem schon publiziert sein sollte, und dies ein nachfolgender Aufsatz sein muss, der sich auf diese veröffentliche Umfrage bezieht.*

> Wie wir bereits gezeigt haben, *ist* für Jugendliche heutzutage das wichtigste, toll auszusehen. Welche Auswirkungen hat das für ihre berufliche Zukunft?

### Fall 2: Die Umfrage ist von jemandem ganz anders, du ziehst sie in Zweifel

In diesem Fall musst du unbedingt im Konjunktiv schreiben, um dich von den Inhalten zu distanzieren. Beispiel wäre:

> Laut einer Umfrage von Hans Mustermayr seien Jugendliche heutzutage nur am »toll aussehen« interessiert. Dementgegen steht eine Umfrage von Jutta Ostermeier, die behauptet, dass »zocken« unter männlichen Jugendlichen die größte Priorität habe.

---

Du liegst wahrscheinlich in der Mitte dazwischen. Je nachdem, wie viel Vertrauen du in die Umfrage hast, desto indikativer und desto unkonjunktiver sollte dein Text sein. Leider kann ich dir darüberhinaus kaum mehr helfen.

Comment: Erwägen wir zwei Fälle. 1) Die Umfrage habe ich in einer Zeitschrift gesehen, kenne den Author doch nicht. 2) Die Umfrage ist von einer Kollege meines Kolleges meines Kolleges. Ich kenne ihn ein bisschen, er soll es sorgfältig gemacht haben, ich kann aber meine Hand nicht ins Feuer legen, dass es völlig korrekt ist. Soll ich in beiden Fällen das Konjunktiv benutzen?

Comment: Um sich vom Inhalt zu distanzieren/ihn in Zweifel zu ziehen, sollte man den Konjunktiv II verrwenden (wäre)-

Comment: @wolfgang: Nein, das ginge höchstens, wenn man von der Unrichtigkeit überzeugt ist. Ein großer Unterschied.

Comment: @chirlu: Nun ja, aber der Konjunktiv I drückt meines Erachtens *keinerlei* in-Zweifel-ziehen aus, ich übernehme eben nur keine Verantwortung dafür. Wenn ich etwas "in Zweifel ziehe", dann behaupte ich ja zumindest, dass es keine sichere Tatsache ist, und dafür kann ich sehr wohl bereits den KJ2 verwenden: "X behauptet, es gäbe am Mars Leben; ich aber finde, wir sollten noch auf Beweise warten". Das ist noch ein Schritt unter "von der Unrichtigkeit überzeugt", aber es ist "in Zweifel ziehen".

Comment: @wolfgang Ich würde in dem Fall schreiben »Die Nasa behauptet, es **gebe** auf dem Mars leben; aber ich finde, wir sollten noch auf Beweise von der ESA warten«, also Konjunktiv I. In gesprochener Sprache nimmt man eh den zweiten (wenn man nicht gleich würdevoll spricht). Alles, was ich mir nicht zu eigen mache, ist Konjunktiv I – zumindest für mich als Wissenschaftler (schließlich haben diejenigen, die ich in Zweifel ziehe, Gründe, warum sie das publiziert haben, auch wenn ich den Gründen nicht zustimme).

Answer (score 1):

Die direkte Rede ist hier völlig angemessen, egal ob die Teilnehmer ausdrücklich "Ich will toll aussehen!" gesagt oder nur die entsprechende Aussage angekreuzt haben. Fraglich ist, ob der erweiterte Infinitiv (*auszusehen*) verwendet werden sollte; bei derart kurzen Phrasen ist der einfache Infinitiv aber sehr üblich.

Comment: Voll an der Frage vorbei. :-) Es geht um _sei_ und _folge_ (indirekte Rede) vs. _ist_ und _folgt_ (direkte Rede). Wie schon kommentiert, ohne mehr Kontext nicht zu sagen.

Comment: @chirlu... man muss fairerweise sagen, dass der einzige Hinweis darauf, was OP wissen will versteckt in der Frage ist. Die Überschrift fragt nach indirekter Rede. Von daher ist die Antwort durchaus eine Antwort auf die Frage, wie sie denn aktuell noch ist.